# SQL To Pull Linked List(ish) Data From Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Thank you in advance for your help...

I want to get the parent site list/informatoin for a site based on its ID.  There is a site hierarchy described in 2 tables, like this:

```
table: site
- id  (PK)
- name

table: hierarchy
- siteid   (PK) (siteid   => site.id)
- parented (PK) (parented => site.id)
- topid         (topid    => site.id)
```

For example, you may have the following data in the tables:

```
site:
id,name
0,Earth
1,US
2,NY
3,GA
4,Queens
5,Farmers' Market
6,Buckhead

hierarchy:
siteid,parented,topid
5,4,1
4,2,1
2,1,1
1,0,1
5,6,1
6,3,1
3,1,1
1,0,1
```

I want to get all the parents of the Farmers's Market sites.  There are markets in both Buckhead and Queens.

How do I make SQL walk / recurse up the tree to get something like this if I want the parent list for site id=5?:

```
site_name,parent_name
Farmers' Market,Queens
Queens,NY
NY,Earth
Farmers' Market,Buckhead
Buckhead,GA
GA,Earth
```

It occurs to me that there may need to be more than one row in the site table for Farmers' Market, but, I don't think so...

Thanks for your help,

David

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect By Prior Equivalent for MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631048/connect-by-prior-equivalent-for-mysql)

Comment: Add a herarcy-level column to you hierarchy table. Then join the hierarchy-table hierarchy-level times to itself and vary the join key.