# php and mysql dynamic breadcrumps

Tags: php, mysql, breadcrumbs

I have a website that list all food sources; In my db I've made a MySQL table named `[foods]`

[image: food table]

In my page, when the user click the category he gets list of its all children.  in my case

```
food
 -- Plants
 ---- Vegetable
 ------ Aubergine
 ------ Broad_bean
 ------ Broccoli
 ------ Carrot
 ---- Fruits
 ------ Apple
 ------ Apricot
 ------ Banana
 ------ Cherry
 ------ Clementine
 ------ Guava
 -- Animals
```

**Now**, I want to make a dynamic breadcrumbs navigation in the top of my page, something like

```
Food > Plants > Fruits > Banana
```

So the user can navigate through them.

I've tried several queries to get this but with no luck.

Every time I get only the first parent of the category only

So if I am in `Banana` page I only get the `Fruits` category, nothing deeper.

I know I have to use `while` loop `where cat_parent_id != 0` but I couldn't figure-out how  to implement it the right way!

**here is a code snippet I've tried**

```
$cat_parent_id = $_REQUEST['cat_id'];

$q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM foods WHERE cat_id = $cat_parent_id");
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{
  echo $name = $r['cat_name'];
}
```

I really appreciate your help in this regards

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You should give what you tried so that it can be fixed. Better than giving you another answer. :)

Comment: Maybe you can get some ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631048/connect-by-prior-equivalent-for-mysql

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score -1):

u have to use recursive function. means check

for ex:

```
function show_breadcumb($cat_id)
{   
  $q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM foods WHERE cat_id = $cat_id");
  while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
  {
     $name = $r['cat_name'];
     $string.= $name .">".$string
  }
  //check if this category has any parent again call this fucntion
  if( has parent  ) { show_breadcumb($cat_id) }
  else return $string;
}
```

Means ur loop should continue find category up to first level.

Comment: Please use English when answering questions. Abbreviations like "ur" are not just irritating, but extremely confusing to those that do not know slang.