# Select all the child of a parent

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this table on `MySQL`

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| ID | ID_parent | name       |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 7  | 5         | ....       |
| 10 | 7         | ....       |
| 11 | 5         | ....       |
| 20 | 7         | ....       |
| 30 | 10        | ....       |
| 45 | 20        | ....       |
```

For the `ID=7` How can I select all child that its anchor is `7` => `(10,20,30,45)` ?

Comment: Is the number of levels somehow limited?

Comment: Then it's not possible with one query when you have table in this format. There are special table formats which enable you to query them like this. Or do each level with one query and do the recursion in PHP or whatever language you use.

Comment: I'm not so sure it's impossible. According to [this article](http://guilhembichot.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html) recursice ctes are supported on MySql.

Comment: look for `CONNECT BY` or better its `MySQL` alternative, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631048/connect-by-prior-equivalent-for-mysql) ... heck, `MySQL` doesn't support anything beside the plain join, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

We dcide to add a extra column `ancestors` where we put all the ancestor parent of a child separated by a `,` like this

```
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
| ID | ID_parent | name       | ancestors  |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+
| 7  | 5         | ....       | ,7,        |
| 10 | 7         | ....       | ,10,7,     |
| 11 | 5         | ....       | ,11,5,     |
| 20 | 7         | ....       | ,20,7,     |
| 30 | 10        | ....       | ,30,10,7,  |
| 45 | 20        | ....       | ,45,20,7,  |
```

In my case i choose to put the child and it's ancestors between `,` and i start and i finish with the `,` maybe different approach can be used depend on situation.

So now we can easily get the child of a parent or get the parent ancestor of a child.

- To found all child of a parent we use `LIKE %,idparent,%`
- To found all parents of a child we split the field `ancestors` of this child
  and we can get all ancestor so we loop over them.