# Remove assigned users from database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table:

```
| staff_id | leader_id |   team_role  | importance |
+          +           +              +            +
| 1001037  |  1000321  |      HOD     |      1     |
| 1001037  |  1000322  |      HOD     |      1     |
| 1001037  |  1001037  |  Supervisor  |      2     |
| 1001094  |  1001037  |    Checker   |      3     |
| 1001075  |  1001037  |    Checker   |      3     |
| 1001096  |  1001075  | Squad Leader |      4     |
| 1000393  |  1001094  | Squad Leader |      4     |
| 1000465  |  1001094  | Squad Leader |      4     |
| 1000585  |  1001075  | Squad Leader |      4     |
| 1000664  |  1000585  | Team Member  |      5     |
| 1000583  |  1000585  | Team Member  |      5     |
| 1000570  |  1000465  | Team Member  |      5     |
| 1000316  |  1000465  | Team Member  |      5     |
```

In php it look like this:

[image]
[image]

If I want to remove user with `staff_id = 1001075` I need to remove all assigned to this user ids. So it will be ids where `1001075` is `leader_id`. I am able to this but I also need to remove users going down to the tree so where `leader_id= 1001075` is will be `1000585` Then I need to remove users where `leader_id= 1000585`

In the end I need to delete these users with `staff_id`:

```
1001075
1001096
1000585
1000664
1000583
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you written anything in an attempt to achieve this goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

- Recursively query for all the ids to find out all the children and delete the rows one by one. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631048/connect-by-prior-equivalent-for-mysql) answer for approaches to recursively query the ids.
- Run an `ALTER TABLE` script and make `leader_id` a foreign key, referencing to `staff_id` of the same table, and define with `ON DELETE CASCADE`. By this way, when you delete a leader row, it will delete all the subsequent rows, e.g.:

  `ALTER TABLE table
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_leader_id FOREIGN KEY (leader_id) REFERENCES table(staff_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;`

I would prefer the second approach.